How can I export an excel file with highlighting and comments in R?
I would like to know if there is a way to export a data frame/tibble from R as an .xlsx file with highlighting and comments added natively from the R console rather than post-processing in Excel.
I have a data set that consists of binned data calculated as an average of raw morphological measurement data from multiple individuals that is to be used for a correspondence analysis. Dummy example is below.
df<-data.frame(
taxon=c('Taxon1','Taxon2','Taxon3'),
blerp=c(1,1,NA),
herp=c(3,1,1),
derp=c(2,NA,2))

In addition to input values calculated directly from the raw data, missing values are going to be interpolated or estimated with approximate values using one of several methods, such as inputting values from closely related species.
The standard practice for these kinds of analyses in my field is to produce a datasheet where estimated values have color-coded cells based on the method used to estimate them, and then justification is provided in a comment explaining how the estimated value was produced. The result would look something like below for the provided dummy dataset.

However, previous authors did this by inputting estimated values and comments manually; because my dataset is much larger I would like to do this using R.
What I would ideally want to do is export two separate data frames as .xlsx files. One containing just the data calculated directly from the measured material, and then one with interpolated values highlighted with different colors for different methods and comments tagged where appropriate. I know how to export .xlsx files from R (write.xlsx)but it is unclear how highlighting and comments can be added from an R console.
One method I had thought might work is to use some function that compares all cells in the original spreadsheet/data frame A with the spreadsheet/data frame A', and then any cells that differ between the two versions would be marked with highlighting. This could be done multiple times for different interpolation methods (i.e., differences between A and A' in yellow, A' versus A'' in orange). However, I do not know how to accomplish this with code. I am also completely lot as to whether there is any way to add comments.
I would like to do this formatting and annotation with machine learning if possible because the analysis is being formatted as an RMarkdown file. If I had to input all estimated values and mark them as such manually in Excel post-processing, it would mean I would have to redo the file by hand every time I had to adjust values or add new rows. Similarly, because the analysis is being conducted in R Markdown, if I cannot annotate the file natively in R this would mean I could not just run the analysis using a single RMarkdown file, I would have to run one RMarkdown file to produce the initial dataset, then manually mark it up in Excel with the interpolated values, and then put that file in a second RMarkdown document in order to run the correspondence analysis, which does not seem efficient for replicability.

Formatting and comments can be added using the openxlsx package. For example:
library(openxlsx)

# writing the data to a new workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb, 1, df)

# apply to all cells with NAs:
apply(which(is.na(df), arr.ind = T), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(cell) {
  # overwrite the missing value
  writeData(wb, 1, 
    sample(1:3, 1), # your interpolated value (here a random number)
    startRow = cell['row']+1, startCol = cell['col']
  )
  # highlight the cell
  addStyle(wb, 1,
    createStyle(fgFill = 'orange'),
    rows = cell['row']+1, cols = cell['col']
  )
  # add a comment to the cell
  writeComment(wb, 1, col = cell['col'], row = cell['row']+1,
    comment = createComment("Filled in with random number")
  )
}) |> invisible()

# view the workbook (there's also a function for saving it to disk)
openXL(wb)



Is there a way to identify cell number by row and column name (e.g., "Taxon1, blerp"), or is that a bit too far since Excel doesn't see these as row/column names?

@user2352714 Not built-in AFAIK, but you could do something like which(df$taxon == 'Taxon1') + 1 for the row and which(colnames(df) == 'blerp') for the column.
